# What should I do when I want to change close reason from "need debugging info" to "can not reproduce"?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

Someone posted a question without enough information to reproduce the issue, so I voted to close the question as 'Needs debugging details', then pointed out in a comment that I need more details to reproduce the issue.

The OP then posted the details needed to reproduce the issue, and I tested it, but I am unable to reproduce the issue locally. Now I want to change my vote from "needs more debugging details" (which was true when I cast the vote), to "Not reproducible" (at least I can't reproduce it locally). It appears that I can only retract my vote, and the website informs me "I will not be able to vote again after retracting".

What's the correct thing to do in this situation?

BTW, the specific thread is [PHP CURL does not automatically add Content-Length header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385119/php-curl-does-not-automatically-add-content-length-header/61385811#61385811)

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to reopen a question just to close it again for some other reason. It needs at least three fresh people, 3 reopen and 3 close votes. I suggest to just leave a comment.

Comment: *Generally* - it's not worth it to change your close vote. Unless it's wildly off -  e.g., voting for a dupe but it's not a correct one. For similar enough reasons, it's OK to leave it. Question needs to be closed. Leave a comment for what needs to be fixed. In *this case* - you would actually be wrong to change your vote. It still needs debugging information - if you cannot reproduce it, then there is missing information. "Cannot reproduce" is more for when the question asker no longer experiences it but there is no good solution.

Comment: Technically speaking it still needs more debugging details if you can't reproduce it with what was posted so the close reason isn't THAT far off. I see you opted to post an answer instead so now there's even less reason to change the close vote. Since it sits at only 1 vote it's still possible that it will end up being closed as "not reproducible" if two others vote to close for that reason.

Comment: Convince yourself it really doesn't matter. If that fails, make friends with a moderator and convince them to do the reopen-and-close-again dance for you.

Comment: Note that, in this particular case, I don't think the question needs to be closed at all. Your answer (saying "I cannot reproduce; this code works properly") is a valid answer to the question. You would close *instead* of answering.